# Where'd all my compiler warnings go? VS2019, C# 9, .Net 5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, compiler-warnings, .net-5, c#-9.0

I haven't used C# for anything besides little quick-and-dirty things in several years, but now I'm starting something more "real", so I've started using the latest non-preview stuff: C# 9, .Net 5, and VS 2019. I've found that there are lots of little compiler warnings that I am used to having, and that I liked having, that I can't seem to enable anymore.

I think most of these things were stylistic, like "Closing bracket should be followed by a blank line" or "Function is missing documentation header". Stuff I used to get from, I think, FxCop and/or StyleCop. Possibly all of them are things like this, but I'm not sure of that.

I've seen a lot of writings indicating that all this has been changed in the recent versions of .Net, C#, and/or VS, so I've been reading documentation about it. I am, unfortunately, apparently not understanding it properly. So, I've also tried lots of random scattershot combinations of different things, including but perhaps not limited to:

- Nugetting or not Nugetting Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers
- `<EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>` `true` or `false`
- `<EnableNETAnalyzers>` `true` or `false`
- `<RunAnalyzerDuringBuild>` `true` or `false`
- Manually using "Analyze/Run Code Analysis/On Solution" vs. hoping for the build to do it for me.

It's possible or even probable that I haven't tried all such combinations, but nothing I've tried so far has helped.

I'm definitely getting warnings in a "generally speaking" sense - for example, if I set `<Nullable>` to `enable`, I can make various warnings like "Dereference of a possible null reference" happen. So it's apparently not simply that VS or whatever is somehow configured to only show Error and above.

Any suggestions on how I get this stuff back now that I'm using C# 9, .Net 5, and VS 2019? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/roslyn-analyzers-overview — and yes, brace position is entirely *layout* stylistic (it is also not possible to analyze from compiled code). I use ReSharper as third-party tool for such stylistic / formatting rules (so I’m not longer what comes with VS and what is extra..). Maybe you were using a third-party extension before?

Comment: @user2864740, thanks, I'll take a look, but like I said I've read a bunch of stuff like that and I'm apparently not understanding it properly. I'm kind of hoping for something like "Start a console app project, go to the project properties page, tab Blah, check the "Do Thing" box, and uncheck the "Do Other Thing" box.

Comment: @user2864740 Hmmm... I was using Resharper before, and I'm not now, but I seem to recall having gotten these sort of warnings by Nugetting packages like "Stylecop.Analyzers" or "Microsoft.Analyzers.FxCop" (not sure that those are the real names). The documentation I've read seems to indicate that those things are now deprecated in favor of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers, and that that is enabled by default by VS 2019 in a C# 9/.NET 5 project.

Comment: If it’s in VS standard, such options are likely under either the “Editors” or “C# -> Code Style”.

Comment: FxCop is indeed dead. It was never responsible for squiggles about layout rules though (even with the name “style”) — it worked on already compiled code and was one of the large limitations.

Comment: On a whim, I tried Nugetting Stylecop.Analyzers, and everything suddenly became a whole lot more like I had expected. Maybe I'm just misreading/misinterpreting the stuff about Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers having replaced the old stuff I had been using.

Comment: @BobVesterman Hi Bob, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as the answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT, well, I'm not so sure that it's all that good of an answer. I gave up on it after some time using it, as it seems like maybe it's not updated for .NET 5, giving warnings about things related to new features. For example, if I remember correctly, it will warn about something like "Blah blah = new();".